# How to get the name of child realtime database kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the email (in this case mikeyreid2002@gmail.com) however I don't see any method I can use that gets me the name of the child instead of the value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzonn.png

Answer (score 0):

In this case the email is the key of a nested object. You need to iterate over the collection documents and use their id as email

```
 firestore.collection("Users").get().result.documents.forEach { 
    Log.d("Key", "${it.key}")   
}
```

You can also use higher-order function to transform the documents, associate (using the email) and deserialize the data.

Comment: Thank you! What type of variable is firestore?

Comment: I assumed you are using Firestore, but you can do the same with realtime database.